# Find the rate of change $dy/dx$ where $x= x_0$

Tags: calculus

$y= 3x+5$; $x_0=-1$

I know the answer is $3$ but I don't know how to solve it. Can you please help me?

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dx}=3$, a constant. So its value does not depend on $x_0$.

Comment: So, that's it? Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Sometimes when a problem is *too* simple, it can be puzzling. You might have had an easier time with $y=x^3+5x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
{dy \over dx} \equiv \lim_{h \to 0} {f(x+h)-f(x) \over h} \\
$$

Where $y = f(x)$.

$$
{dy \over dx} = \lim_{h \to 0} {3 x + 3 h + 5 - 3 x - 5 \over h} = 3
$$

Comment: That is the formula that we have been using in class and I didn't understand it. However, you have made it so much clear! Thank you!

Comment: @SeanHaugh Are you sure you mean $\equiv$, instead of $=$?

Comment: @gekkostate, I'm not Sean Haugh, but the $\equiv$ sign is also used for definitions or identities.

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams oh! I was not aware of that. Thank you for the clarification.